# OpenGL is missing - AMD Radeon HD 7300 Series

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I just installed a fresh copy of Windows 8 on my desktop: After updating everything, and yes - even my graphics card I tried to start up Minecraft but I get a `OpenGL is missing` error.

[Here's a DXdiag of my system](https://gist.github.com/8628afe5489b2a53ffb7),

And from it, my card:

```
Card name: AMD Radeon HD 7300 Series (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.20)
```

I've updated my drivers and even tried to install it from Devices. I did notice that after installing, the  Control Panel for my Graphics card is different and it's called AMD Vision Engine Control Center. I can't configure none of my flatpanel settings.... I kinda wish I never upgraded but it's to late now.

I'm really looking for help here, as  I can't even get some features of Photoshop working, which is part of my job. I am really looking for a fix, thank you.

Comment: Try installing the 12.11 Catalyst beta drivers

Comment: this, correct? http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst1211betadriver.aspx
Did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Safe mode and run Driver Sweeper and remove all the [display drivers](http://www.guru3d.com/content-page/guru3d-driver-sweeper.html)(only display!).

Reboot back into normal mode and install the drivers again, it should be fixed if a corrupted install is preventing OpenGL files from registering.

The ATI ogl driver has not been registered, re installing will fix it, this driver must be registered

> C:\Windows\system32\atioglxx.dl

But it's not in your PC as seen from dxdiag dump.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause me not to use my screen?

Comment: Your display will work even without the drivers.

Comment: This isn't a Windows 8 Issue?

Comment: It could be, try this out and see if it fixes your computer

Comment: Okay. Went to safe boot, removed drivers. rebooted. reinstalled drivers from AMD site and it still doesn't work. Now I get this error: AMD Control Center can not start

Answer (score 1):

Afaik the default Win8 WDM drivers are only a stub. Neither of them (both on Nvidia or AMD cards) seemed to support OpenGL. Maybe because MS favours directX.

For me, it was resolved by installing vendor drivers, but on some machines bitmap fonts (wglusebitmapfont) seems to be corrupted.

(added later: the font corruption was unrelated, and due to a not detached texture. Some cards/drivers (e.g. near all intels) would texture glcalllists output, and some not)

Comment: Found the cause:some intel cards seem to dislike having a PBO bound while drawing wglusebitmapped fonts.